# model between a categorical variable and numerical variable over time

Tags: machine-learning

I have a dataset which has 4 fields as below:

```
Day                Category    #people    #Rank   
2011-01-01          A            100       10
2011-01-01          B            120       12 
2011-01-02          A             50       13
2011-01-02          C            122       42
2011-01-02          D             20       20
...                 ...           ...      ....
```

In the category filed I have 10 category then I want to model the relationship between  the Category and number of people.

I have used Multiple linear regression on the category filed but the R2 is so small after I remove the variables using backward elimination technique.
Could you please suggest me what is a best approach? 
Shall I consider the time series?

Comment: don't use stepwise:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/258026/are-there-any-circumstances-where-stepwise-regression-should-be-used